# how to include currency convertor?

Tags: iphone

Is There any free API for currency convertor for iphone.  So I can get live updates for currency convertor for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo Finance has a simple one:

http://freeapis.blogspot.com/2010/05/yahoo-api-for-currency-exchange-rate.html